# Stop animation at a certain point and start up from that point again

Tags: swift, animation

**Background**

Hi all! I am creating a timer feature for my application.

Part of this timer includes a progress ring around the actual countdown numbers that fills as the timer progresses.

I added the image below in case my explanation was not easy to understand.

[image: countdown timer UI]

My goal is for the green stroke to stop animating when the "pause" button is tapped, and to continue animating when the "continue" button is tapped.

So far, the green stroke only animates correctly after pressing a start button.

To provide more background on how my code works, I added the content below.

To make the circle, I create a CAShapeLayer Object (shapeLayer) whose .path is equal to a circular UIBezierPath .CGPath

```
let center = view.center
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: view.bounds.width/2.5, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 7
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Next, I animate the outside stroke using a CABasicAnimaton Object "basicAnimation". I do all my animation in the doAnimate() function detailed below.

```
func doAnimate(n: Int){
        if n == 1{ //if n is 1, start from zero
            basicAnimation.toValue = 0.80  // my circles start point is 0, and the endpoint at the top is .8 not 1
        }//end of if
        if n == 2{ //if n is 2, the timer was already started and the pause button has been pressed
            //stop the animation where it is at
        }//end of if
        if n == 3{//if n is 3, the continue button has been pressed
            // continue the animation from where it was stopped
        }//end of if

        basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1500) //this is a set 25 minute timer which is why the duration is 1500
        basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }//end of func
```

**Problem**

In all of my IBOUtlet button functions, I call the doAnimate function with an integer n passed in.

The purpose of my integer 'n' is to decide where the stroke should be on the progress bar.

If n == 1, the stroke will start from 0.

If n == 2, that would mean the user has pressed the pause button, and I need the stroke to stop and hold where it is.

If n == 3, then the user pressed the continue button and I need the stroke to continue again.

I cannot get my animated stroke to pause when I press the pause button.

Similarly, I cannot get it to continue when I press the continue button.

I have been researching all day for code to fix this issue, and I cannot find any.

**Question**

I need the stroke to stop animating and stay where it is at after pressing the pause button.

I need the stroke to continue animating if the continue button is pressed.

How do I stop an animation and then make it pick back up from that point later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> I need the stroke to stop animating and stay where it is at after pressing the pause button.

You can use [`presentation()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentation) to retrieve “a copy of the presentation layer object that represents the state of the layer as it currently appears onscreen”, i.e., the state of the layer mid-animation. Use that to set the `strokeEnd` before you remove the animation:

```
if let presentationLayer = progressShapeLayer.presentation() {
    progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = presentationLayer.strokeEnd
}
progressShapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: animationKey)
```

> I need the stroke to continue animating if the continue button is pressed.

Use this `strokeEnd` value for your `fromValue` when you restart the animation.

---

For example:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CircularProgressView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var duration:  CFTimeInterval = 10
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1  { didSet { updatePaths() } }

    private(set)   var isRunning = false
    private        var elapsed: CFTimeInterval = 0
    private        var startTime: CFTimeInterval!
    private        let animationKey = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".strokeEnd"

    private let backgroundShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()
    
    private let progressShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2319213939, green: 0.5, blue: 0.224438305, alpha: 1).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        return shapeLayer
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }
    
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePaths()
    }
    
    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1 / 3
    }
}

// MARK: - Public interface

public extension CircularProgressView {
    func start(duration: CFTimeInterval) {
        self.duration = duration
        reset()
        resume()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        guard
            isRunning,
            let presentation = progressShapeLayer.presentation()
        else {
            return
        }
        
        elapsed += CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime
        progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = presentation.strokeEnd
        progressShapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: animationKey)
    }
    
    func resume() {
        guard !isRunning else { return }
        
        isRunning = true
        startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = elapsed / duration
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.duration = duration - elapsed
        animation.delegate = self
        progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        progressShapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: animationKey)
    }
    
    func reset() {
        isRunning = false
        progressShapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: animationKey)
        progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        elapsed = 0
    }
}

extension CircularProgressView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        isRunning = false
    }
}

// MARK: - Utility

private extension CircularProgressView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundShapeLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(progressShapeLayer)
    }
    
    func updatePaths() {
        let radius = (min(bounds.width, bounds.height) - lineWidth) / 2
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -.pi / 2, endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
        
        backgroundShapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        progressShapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        
        backgroundShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        progressShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Rob, the presentationLayer retrieves a copy of the state of the layer, but the animation continues. If I press the pause button again, it simply resets back to the retrieved layer. The removeAnimation function is not working for me. I also tried view.layer.removeAllAnimation(), and that would not work either. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: @Stryka - See example.